# How can I make icon child and text child appear only if the items equal 1 or greater and make them invisible if they are 0

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart

How can I make icon child and text child appear only if the items equal 1 or greater

I am trying to hide the minus button and the 0 (which shows how many items) if the total equals 0. So only show the minus icon and the total items only if it is 1 or greater and make them invisible if they are 0.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClassName extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ClassNameState createState() => _ClassNameState();
}

class _ClassNameState extends State<ClassName> {

int _counter = 0;

void _incrementCounter() {
setState(() {
  _counter++;
});
}

void _decrementCounter() {
setState(() {
  if (_counter != 0)
  _counter--;
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0, top: 7.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.fill,image: 
AssetImage("image.png"))
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text("Black t-shirt", style: 
TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            Spacer(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 52.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("£17.99", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
FontWeight.bold),),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(icon: 
Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline, color: Colors.blue,), onPressed: 
_decrementCounter),
                      Text('$_counter'),
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.control_point, 
color: Colors.blue,), onPressed: _incrementCounter),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Visibilty widget:

```
Visibility(
  visible: totalItems > 0,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Icon(...),
      Text(...),
    ],
   ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helped.